# How to fix "returned a non-zero code: 7" when building docker image

Tags: confluent-platform

I'm a newer to Docker, when i follow https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/development.html#create-a-docker-image-containing-local-connectors to build a Docker image with local connector, i got some issue.

below is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:5.3.0

COPY kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip /tmp/kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt /tmp/kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip
```

when I run "docker build . -t my-custom-image:1.0.0", got below error:

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.876MB Step 1/3 : FROM
>   confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:5.3.0  ---> b1491496b48d Step 2/3 :
>   COPY kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip
>   /tmp/kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip  ---> Using cache  --->
>   85689e66c40a Step 3/3 : RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt
>   /tmp/kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip  ---> Running in 1d3486732517
>   Running in a "--no-prompt" mode Failed to unzip
>   '/tmp/kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip' into
>   '/tmp/confluent-hub-tmp7724578044817786588' String index out of range:
>   -1
>
> Error: Unknown error The command '/bin/sh -c confluent-hub install
>   --no-prompt /tmp/kafka-connect-solr-sink-0.0.1.zip' returned a non-zero code: 7

Anyone can kindly help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

From the Docker file ,Ensure you set the required proxy settings so that you do not get this error.
In Dockerfile....

ENV http_proxy <proxy_host>:
ENV https_proxy <proxy_host>:

After adding this before running other commands it